# Merge lists based on value in separate "key" list

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

I have a list like the following:

```
test = [[2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 6, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7], [4, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 5], [5, 3, 2, 4], [4, 3, 5, 2, 6]]
```

and another list `key` which describes how the original list needs to be merged:

```
key = ["one", "two", "one", "two"]
```

I want the "one"s to be merged and the "two"s to be merged in the original `test` list.

output should look like:

```
[[2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 6, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7, 5, 3, 2, 4], [4, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 5, 2, 6]]
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Why couldn't you have made your key numbers instead of strings :(

Comment: @user3483203 This is an example, my actual key is string, so I wanted to keep data type the same.

Comment: What is the maximum cardinality of the ["one","two","three"] list, if any?

Comment: @Attersson Currently only 2 but the ideal solution would scale up as far as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe a dictionary is the most appropriate solution here.  A dictionary allows you to keep track of which partition is associated to which key easily.  If you just use a list with the values it can be more difficult to map a partition to a key.

Here is a solution using a **`collections.defaultdict`**:

```
dct = defaultdict(list)

for i, e in enumerate(key):
  dct[e].extend(test[i])

# defaultdict(list,
#        {'one': [2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 6, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7, 5, 3, 2, 4],
#         'two': [4, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 5, 2, 6]})

# If you want the values
print(list(dct.values()))
```

Output:

```
[[2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 6, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7, 5, 3, 2, 4], [4, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 5, 2, 6]]
```

Comment: why this line, can you explain `dct = defaultdict(list)`

Comment: @pyd It creates a dictionary which maps to lists by default. Meaning, if you want to reach to a non-present key, it'll have an empty list as default.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @BcK

Comment: How can the order of the final "key" be confirmed? Like how do I know whether the output is in the order "one", "two" or the opposite? For this example it's easy to just check, but for my actual use I need a way to output a new key showing the order.

Comment: @KeshavM if you printed `dct.items()`, you would see each partition along with its associated key

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you the following answer **without any import** AND **keeping the order of the keys** in the resulting list. This is not optimized in term of execution time, but easily readable. Note also that if the lists `key` and `test` do not have the same length, then the algorithm will run with the shortest length without raising any error (behavior of `zip`):

```
test = [[2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 6, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7], [4, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 5], [5, 3, 2, 4], [4, 3, 5, 2, 6]]
key = ["one", "two", "one", "two"]

d = {}
orderedKeys = []

for k,t in zip(key,test):
    if k in d.keys():
        d[k] += t
    else:
        d[k] = t
        orderedKeys.append(k)


print([d[k] for k in orderedKeys])
# [[2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 6, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7, 5, 3, 2, 4], [4, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 5, 2, 6]]
```

Comment: Yes, pretty nice. One question: don't you need to initialize d[k] to [] before adding to it?

Comment: Thanks. No need to do that, because when I do `d[k] += t`, I have already checked just before that `k` is a key of `d` (meaning that `d[k]` is already initialized).

Comment: Right. Perfect.

Comment: I didn't know `zip` function existence. Great discovery!

Comment: How can the order of the final "key" be confirmed? Like how do I know whether the output is in the order "one", "two" or the opposite? For this example it's easy to just check, but for my actual use I need a way to output a new key showing the order.

Comment: Well I can suggest you to just print the `orderedKeys` list: it shows the order of the output.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- `zip()` the two lists which will create `[(first, second), ...]`, where `first` comes from `key` and `second` is the values you want to group
- sort (`sorted()`) on the `first`
- group (`itertools.groupby()`) on the `first`
- flatten (`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`) the `second`

e.g.:

```
In []:
import operator as op
import itertools as it

first, second = op.itemgetter(0), op.itemgetter(1)
[list(it.chain.from_iterable(map(second, g)))
 for k, g in it.groupby(sorted(zip(key, test), key=first), first)]

Out[]:
[[2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 6, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7, 5, 3, 2, 4], [4, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 5, 2, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Scalable vanilla solution:**

This solution does not import anything.

```
#all_keys is complete and ordered
all_keys = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"]
max_keys = len(all_keys)

output =[[]*max_keys]

test = [[2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 6, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7], [4, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 5], [5, 3, 2, 4], [4, 3, 5, 2, 6]]
key = ["one", "two", "one", "two"]

for i,entry in enumerate(test):
    output[all_keys.index(key[i])]+=entry
```

Comment: This is not very efficient, having to call `index()` on every key entry is rather slow.

Comment: While turning into O(N^2) it needs no final linear print() and does not import anything. Making it a valid tradeoff alternative to consider.

Answer (score 0):

I propose this solution:

```
test = [[2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 6, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7], 
        [4, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 5], 
        [5, 3, 2, 4], 
        [4, 3, 5, 2, 6]]
key = ["one", "two", "one", "two"]
if len(test) != len(key):
    raise Exception
else:
unique = list(set(key))
total = []
for x in unique:
    pair = (x, [])
    total.append(pair)
for i in range(len(key)):
    s = (key[i], test[i])
    for i in range(len(total)):
        if total[i][0] == s[0]:
            total[i] = tuple([total[i][0],total[i][1]+s[1]])
```

First I use `set` to avoid duplicate values into the `keys` list and once I have the unique values I iterate through both, then I make a tuple composed by `(key, array_value)` and find into my total array where is it to append the chunk.